# DRF how to allow list in serializer CharField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have basic serializers with one CharField, what i want is CharField to allow list.

```
class BasicSr(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    answer = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('answer',)
```

my input :

```
e.g 1 
"answer":["a1", "a2"]
e.g 2
"answer":"this is plain ans"
```

both inputs should allow.

error message while validating serializer

**"Not a valid string."**

Comment: how do you plan to validate them, that they are strings or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new serializer class for that,

```
class MySerializerField(serializers.Field):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # do some validation
        # after validation convert the data into native form
        return data

    def to_representation(self, value):
        # change some representation, if you want
        return value


class BasicSr(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer = MySerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('answer',)
```

Comment: should i create custom field

Comment: Do not forget to put some validation since as of now, literally anything can be passed through `answer` field.